# Linking an Access database to NetBeans IDE 8.02 without using JDBC-ODBC

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

How do I link my database to NetBeans without using jdbc.odbc? When I run the program it doesn't link.

```
public void connect() {
   try {
       String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
       Class.forName(driver);

       String database1 = "jdbc:odbc:database1";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(database1);
       st = con.createStatement();
   }
}
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: a microsoft access database (accdb). sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Do you have include Drive jar file?

Comment: no that doesn't have to be included

Comment: Which Java version are you using? The slow and buggy JDBC/ODBC bridge (which has always been deprecated) has been removed in Java **8**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)

Answer (score 0):

Register you ms-access file (*.accdb) as a odbc data source.
http://www.mundayweb.com/progs/jdbc-odbc-tut.php